# How to show the name of the variable in an AngularJS website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to show the name of the variable in my website written with AngularJS.

for example:
Backend code:

```
$scope.Bundles = {
        Bundle1:["Sensor1","Sensor2"],
        Bundle2:["Sensor1","Sensor2","Sensor3"],
        Bundle3:["Sensor1","Sensor2","Sensor3","Sensor4"]
    }
```

Frontend code:

```
<label  ng-repeat="name in Bundles">
                    <div> *Want to show "Bundle#" (name), instead of it's value (the sensors)* </div>
                </label>
```

Some notes:

- From google searches, I always find people asking how to show the value of the variable, {{name}}, I know that, haven't found anything like the question im asking here
- I need it because later in the code I will need to do a ng-repeat with "sensor in name" to show the sensors separately, so I really need a concrete solution and not a dirty one with another array holding the names.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access both the key and value using:

```
<label ng-repeat="(key, value) in Bundles">
    <div> *Want to show {{ key }}, instead of it's value {{ value }} (the sensors)* </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the super quick answer, it's working fantastic, just what I needed (I still need to wait 9 minutes to mark it xD)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tuple returned by the ng-repeat as stated in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<label ng-repeat="(key,value) in Bundles">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascipt Object.keys(arr) to get all the keys and then iterate to the keys using ng-repeat.

```
$scope.BundleNumbers = Object.keys($scope.Bundles)
```

$scope.BundleNumbers  will have ["Bundle1", "Bundle2", "Bundle3"]

```
<label  ng-repeat="name in BundleNumbers">
 {{name}}
</label>
```

The other and efficient/angular way to do is :

```
<label ng-repeat="(key,value) in Bundles">{{key}} </label>
```

Reference links: 
                [Angular JS ng Repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)
                [JavaScript Object keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)